# How to create a list of variables and reference them?

Tags: symbols

I was trying to create a list of `n` variables such as `x = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 5}]`, which be done by using `Symbol`. However, if after that, I want to assign values to those variables, I could not figure out how to properly reference a variable using `x` and an index (I prefer this method because I may need to reference the variables in a loop). For example, in the code that follows, `x[[1]] = 5` does not assign the value to `x1`. How could I reference `x1` properly using `x` and an index?

[image]

Comment: How about just using `x[1]`, `x[2]`, etc. as variables? (after `Clear[x]` I mean). I think making a list of variables and then trying to refer to them is needlessly complicated.

Comment: @Roman Good point. By using `x[1], x[2], ...` and then assign them values, it is essentially defininga function `x` with some discrete values, right?

Comment: Colloquially speaking, yes. Strictly speaking, there are no functions in Mathematica, and you're assigning [DownValues](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) to the symbol `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I would suggest indexing using arguments (`x[1], x[2], ...`), you can simply add [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html)  on the lhs of the assignment as

```
x = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 5}]
Evaluate@x[[1]] = 5
x
x1
```

> {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}
>
> 5
>
> {5, x2, x3, x4, x5}
>
> 5